# Any issues if we use individual cell identifier for each Cell in UITableView-iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In the below code i have used individual cell identifier for each cell,Which works well.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   NSString *identifier =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID_%d",indexPath.row];
   UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

   if(cell==nil)
   {
      UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
      cell.textLabel.text=@"data";
   }
   return cell;

}
```

Any Performance,Memory or any other problem, in the below code?

Answer (score 3):

If you use individual identifier, then the cells will not be reused. Each UITableViewCell will be different.

And in your code, if `cell == nil`, then again you are calling `deque..`.
If there is no cell with identifier, then you have to allocate a new `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 2):

Performance issues without a doubt. The whole point of the cell identifier is that a table view can re-use existing cells quickly rather than creating (and storing) new ones for each row.

The cell idents should be specific to the type of cell. If you have a table view with three 'types' of cell then use three idents.